# How to make framed box using user input and string manipulation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, dimensions

Here is what I have:

```
frame = input("Enter frame character ==> ")
print(frame)
height = int(input("Height of box ==> "))
print(height)
width = int(input("Width of box ==> "))
print(width)
print("Box:")
print(frame*width)
print(frame + " "*height + frame)
space = int((width - height)/2)
print(frame + (" "* space) + "{}X{}".format(width,height) + (" "* space) + frame)
print(frame + " "*height + frame)
print(frame*width)
```

I am supposed to write a program that asks the user for a frame character, and then the height and width of a framed box. Then, output a box of the given size, framed by the given character. Also, I must output the dimensions of the box centered horizontally and vertically inside the box. I will need to put the box dimensions in a string first, and then use its length to figure out
how long the line containing the dimensions should be. I need to be able to print boxes for various different heights and widths, so if I input a width of 11 and height of 8, I need and 11x8 box. Mine just gives a 7x5 box at the moment, and I am stuck.

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5XU4.png)

I cannot use any if statements or loops in this assignment, only string manipulation. I am not sure how to do so in such a way. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have some code written, and it gets me the answer, to the picture above, but I need to be able to make it work so that another set of widths and heights give a different answer. My code, when I input a width of 11, and a height of 8, still gives me a 7x5 box. I am not sure what else to do

Comment: what's the expected behavior if you ask for any box under `3x5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified to not contain any `if` (but using `assert` to ensure some minimum width and height):

```py
def box_str(w, h, c='.'):
    assert len(c) == 1, "c must be single char"
    assert w >= 5, "minimum width: 5"
    assert h >= 3, "minimum height: 3"
    dim = f'{w}x{h}'
    banner = c * w
    pad = ' ' * (w - 2)
    row = c + pad + c
    nleft = len(pad) - len(dim)
    nright = nleft // 2
    nleft -= nright
    rcenter = [c + ' ' * nleft + dim + ' ' * nright + c]
    ntop = h - 2 - 1
    nbot = ntop // 2
    ntop -= nbot
    return '\n'.join([banner] + [row] * ntop + rcenter + [row] * nbot + [banner])
```

Try: `print(box_str(9, 5, '*'))` gives:

```
*********
*       *
*  9x5  *
*       *
*********
```

and `print(box_str(5, 3, '*'))` gives:

```
*****
*5x3*
*****
```

Anything smaller and it raises.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use if statements or loops

Comment: well, if you're willing to let the box look weird if the size is too small to display the dimensions, then remove those tests. There are already no loops so nothing to change on that front.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I will review and add some user input to make the code fit with the assignment rules.